# How to count test cases when using Template (data-driven) in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework to define automation suite, and I have found built-in Template (data-driven) that help me to implement multiple test cases which have similar input (see the test case as below). It works well, except we only get 1 test case in the result report instead of three test cases. There is a solution by adding Template in Settings area, but my suite contains normal test cases and template test cases, so if I put the Template in Settings, then all normal test cases will be compiled failed. So my questions is: Could we count the test cases under template for my scenario ? Final solution is to move template test cases to a new robot file, but I would prefer to find a workaround solution to put all test base (template and non-template) in one file. Thanks in advance.

```
3 Create V4 Address with Object Class In Json
[Template]    User Adds V4 Address In Json
${3_1}    #Server class
${3_2}    #Router class
${3_3}    #Non-exsting object class

RESTAutomationRestInstance                                            | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Thanks

Comment: In short - no, can't be done (at least in the current version of RF, I can't speak for its future); the idea is - a case with a template is a single one, single set of steps, but you feed it with different inputs. If one of them fails - the whole case fails (regardless that the other may have succeeded). And if you want to track each input as different case - use a suite specially designed for that - e.g. set the template on the suite level, making each line a case of its own.

Comment: Thanks, @TodorMinakov.I agree with you, for the current version of RF, it cannot achieve my goal (after day by day digging on google).  The only way mentioned by you is to use the Suite with Template at Suite Level.